# Responsive slider requires refresh to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm adapting a template I found for free but I'm having trouble identifying the cause of a certain issue. When you first load the page, the responsive slider does not load properly and all the text just stacks on top of each other.

If you refresh the page it loads correctly and shows the 3 dots and arrows and only one slide of text at a time. Is this a JS problem, a CSS problem, or is it a problem of which files are being loaded first?

I tried switching around the sequence of files included in the  tag but didn't get it fixed.

The page is available here http://lindseymotors.com

The slides are at the top positioned over the car photo to the left. The headlines read Auto Finder, Warranties, and Financing.

I've tried this in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox on desktop and Chrome and Dolphin on android and it repeats this error on all devices and browsers that I've tried.

Comment: Check your console for errors when loading the page for the first time, your slider threw an error.

Comment: update to the newest version of [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/) - you are using a 2/3 year old version that has issues - i am getting hella css warnings, have you checked your console? also on initial load this error `TypeError: $(...).easyResponsiveTabs is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

So one thing we noticed, as has been pointed out by @Quoid is that error in regards to easyResponsiveTabs which is there the first time but like the slider works after the first refresh, so too does that error disappear.

I think it's most likely due to the fact you have included to jQuery libraries. In your head you have included 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' and then later on you've included 'lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js' which has jquery version v2.1.4.